# Android NDK Debugging in an included library module

Tags: android, android-ndk, lldb, aar, ndk-gdb

I am currently working on an Android app that is using a library that is using the NDK. The library and the app are maintained in separate repositories and are worked on as separate projects. The library is compiled on its own with Gradle and the ndk-build script. The aar output and .so files are then included in the main application.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to use ndk-gdb (or some alternative) to debug the library while running in the main app?

I have the source code for both projects, and if need be I could combine the projects for use with ndk-gdb, but this is very messy and requires a lot of additional work that would not be version controlled.

Comment: If you use Android Studio 2.2 beta, it is possible to do native debugging. Android Studio will launch `lldb`. Be aware that you might have to disable test coverage in your debug build (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=123771)